How many clock cycles does a multiplier take?
Here is a filter.
The following is a snippet from DSP Integrated Circuits (Academic Press Series in Engineering)  by Lars Wanhammar
What's the maximum sample rate for lattice wave filter?

The following is the original paragraph from the author.
"Assume here that the data word length is 12 bits and that the filter is implemented with bit-serial arithmetic using so-called true single-phase clock (TSPC). This type of logic is modeled by model 1, i.e., the latencies for addition, subtraction, and multiplication in this logic style are one clock cycle longer that the theoretical minimum. Thus, we have in this case \$T_{add}\$ = 1 clock cycle and \$T_{mult}\$ = 4 clock cycles."
The author seems to  assume \$T_{mult} = 4 ~clock ~cycles \$ and \$T_{add} = 1 ~clock ~cycles \$. How did this author derive this conclusion?
I still don't understand why and how he has this assumption. Can anyone explain?

@DaveTweed I have changed my question according to your advice.

For fixed point, I don't think 1:4 a bad guess. Note the wording in the hyperlinked question: implemented using so-called [redundant arithmetic]. redundant representation of results allows faster/cheaper implementations, redundant representation of operands drives up cost while not slowing down the operation much.

@greybeard Can you take a look at my update on what the author originally said? Can you understand this assumption?

@greybeard I have added source now

(excellent move to improve other posts, too!)

It depends on the implementation.
You can make a multiplier that operates in just one clock cycle; this is common in high-performance processors that need to do lots of multiplications, like DSPs, modern CPUs, and GPUs.
You can also make a multiplier that takes up much less silicon area, but requires multiple cycles--usually less than 10, but sometimes more--to operate. This is common on older processors and modern low-cost processors where you don't need to maximize computing power, like small microcontrollers.
It will also depend, even within an architecture, on what is being multiplied. 8-bit integer multiplication may not take the same time as 16-bit fixed-point multiplication, which may not take the same time as 64-bit floating-point multiplication. Multiplying a register by a register may not take the same time as multiplying a register by a value in memory, which may not take the same time as multiplying a value in memory by a constant.
Since the author states that multiplication takes four cycles, it's probably safe to assume that that's true in the context of the architecture and data under consideration.

Can you take a look at my update on what the author originally said?
